# Use the "Add More" functionality to a page(template) without submitting the existing form (and values) and submitting in the end

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a ModelForm which asks for his dreams from the users. But I want users to provide with the "Add More" button so that they can submit the form (form fields) all at once without being the headache of reloading the page everytime the user presses **ADD More**

For example, If a user is done with telling its one wish, he/she can **n** number of more wishes and once he/she presses `Submit` , the form should then submit the answer to the DB.

1. How can I make a model for this? Will a single

```
class Wish(model.Model):
    user=models.Foreignkey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    wishes= models.Charfield(max_length=1024)
```

and a form from this model to render the form????

A user can have any number of wishes available in the DB so that he/she can delete at any point of time by checking/unchecking.

Comment: you need JS to accomplish that :)

Comment: Without JS? Not possible?

Comment: @Deshwal the django admin has this exact features when using inlines for a one to many relationships, so you may want to look at how it's implemented (js code etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model seems mostly ok as far as I can tell from your (very vague) specs - I'd just possibly add a timestamp (creation date) to it.

For the "add more" feature, that's (part of) what [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/) are (with a bit of js).

EDIT:

> is the ForeignKey suitable or some other relation? because A user can have many wishes. So how do I connect all of them? I mean two users might say the same wish so there will be n copies of that wish. Good method?

Well, depends on your specs, really. If wishes are "private" to a user (no other user can see them), your design is fine that way - you may have more or less similar wishes indeed, but chances are each user will formulate it slightly differently so you'd need some natural language analysis to spot those "near duplicates".

Now if existing wishes are visible by all users and they can either choose from existing one or create their own, you'll probably need two relationships: a one to many (foreign key) for the "author", and a many to many for users that selected it (including the "author" so you can easily do stats on how many users have the same wishes).

Comment: Is the ```ForeignKey``` suitable or some other relation? because A user can have many wishes. So how do I connect all of them? I mean two users might say the same wish  so there will be ```n``` copies of that wish. Good method?

Comment: I have the ome problem in the forms. Can you please [take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57884248/render-a-checkboxselectmultiple-form-using-the-data-present-in-database-initia). Thanks in advance